# how to approach stackoverflow errors when it is not pointing to our java code

Tags: java, performance, stack-overflow

Could someone help on how to approach stackoverflow errors when it is not pointing to our java code. The stack trace just points to arraylist and some classloader:

```
     !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
  at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:314)
  at sun.misc.URLClassPath.access$000(URLClassPath.java:60)
  at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.next(URLClassPath.java:195)
  at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.hasMoreElements(URLClassPath.java:206)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:416)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.next(URLClassLoader.java:413)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.hasMoreElements(URLClassLoader.java:438)
  at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:27)
  at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:36)
  at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:27)
  at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:36)
  at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:27)
  at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:36)
  at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.findResources(DefaultClassRealm.java:351)
  at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.findResources(RealmClassLoader.java:252)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1041)
  at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.findResources(DefaultClassRealm.java:351)
  at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.findResources(RealmClassLoader.java:252)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1041)
  at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.findResources(DefaultClassRealm.java:351)
  at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.findResources(RealmClassLoader.java:252)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1041)
```

Comment: Have you checked here:             org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.findResources(DefaultClassRealm.java:351) and org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.findResources(RealmClassLoader.java:252)

Answer (score 2):

eh ? This most definitely looks like your code :

```
at org.codehaus.classworlds.UrlUtils.normalizeUrlPath(UrlUtils.java:11)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.findResources(DefaultClassRealm.java:344)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.findResources(RealmClassLoader.java:252)
```

Comment: In my code we perform SVN Checkout certain xml files, so codehaus might be referring to some svn api. What I wanted to convey is its not pointing to any one of the methods written by me.

Comment: @user1782807 What libraries are you using that aren't just in the default java libs? I suggest you report a bug to the creators of those.